# 数値シミュレーションが正規分布になりません

Tags: python, numpy

6,7,8,9,10 から4個の数字をランダムに取り出しその平均を求める操作を40000回繰り返すを以下のコードで書きました。

でもなぜか、真ん中がへこんでいます。

なぜなんでしょうか？

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
t = list()
for i in range(40000):
    s = np.random.randint(6, 11, 4)
    t+= [sum(s)/len(s)]

plt.hist(t)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bin` の幅が太すぎるので、もっと細かく設定しましょう。

```py
plt.hist(t, bins=16)
```

[image: hist]

**追記**

本題とは関係ありませんが、最近は [Random Generator — NumPy v1.21 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) を使う方法が推奨されている様で、以下の様に書きます。

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 40000
M = 4

rg = default_rng()
t = list(map(np.average, rg.integers(6, 11, (N, M))))

plt.hist(t, bins=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。
Random Generator を使ったコードも参考になります。
ありがとうございます。